# Merchant Requesting Sensitive information to validate credit card

Tags: online-payment, legal

I'm trying to subscribe to a cloud service and they are requesting a lot of information. Is there a limit to the information a merchant can legally request in order to let you use a credit card? They claim that my card was identified as a "security risk" even though it is a new account and my name and address are the same for everything.

The most troublesome to me is them asking to see banking statements for the card. Is this legal, or common in the US?

Here's an excerpt of what they are asking for:

> Your account identification (ID) information.
>
> Clear copies of the following documents.
>
> Any one of the following forms of government-issued photo ID of the credit card holder or payment account holder for your Cloud account:
>
> ```
>    National Identification Card
>
>    Passport
>
>    Driver’s License
> ```
>
> A copy of the front side of the credit card used for your Cloud Account.
>
> Note: For security reasons, we recommend that you conceal the middle digits of the credit card number. Make sure that the name of the card holder, card issuing bank and the last four digits of the card number are clearly visible.
>
> A copy of the bank billing statement for your credit card.

Comment: A legal question requires us to know the countries involved.

Comment: Just so you know the fact that it is a new account is probably at least 50% of the reason that it is flagged as a security of fraud risk. In general accounts with a good usage history are preferred to new accounts as identity thieves typically steal identities and use them to create new accounts which the victim doesn't know about.

Comment: Updated the question. It's based in the US. I can understand it's a concern for new accounts - but then it seems they would just make it part of their standard account set-up if they wanted to check it for everyone.

Comment: Just as an aside, I'm assuming you're 100% sure this is a legitimate vendor, and you're also 100% sure you're actually communicating with the actual vendor, and not with someone pretending to be them?

Comment: Origin, we need to know what country that **you** are in.

Comment: @RonJohn - I am also in the US. Since I wrote this question, another company  has requested basically the same information - just for starting up an account.  Dwizum - yes, I'm sure it's with the vendor.